# How to send data from React client app to Spring Boot backend app?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I'm trying to send the current location of a user from the frontend app being developed using React, to the backend app being developed with Spring Boot. I'm aware to use the react-geolocated plugin in the frontend app to retrieve the current location of the user in the react app, I just need a way to send this data to the spring boot application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) node-module. Using this you should be able to make api call to your backend spring boot app.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm trying now to access the api with axios, but it fails having the backend behind a proxy. Here is my package.json file:

[package.json](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/uebgcx5P)

Comment: if your end point is "/updateLocation" then you might have to say axios.post('/updateLocation', {}).then().catch()

Comment: when you said "but it fails", can you please mention what is the output of your network call.

Comment: It is solved now! I have typed:

axios.get("/hello")
      .then(function(response) {
        this.setState({hello: response.data});
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

Instead of:

axios.get("/hello")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({hello: response.data})
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });

Thank you for your help!